# What cell types comprise the median eminence and the tuber cinereum?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

I have tried pretty hard to get a detailed description of what exactly the median eminence and the tuber cinereum are but to no avail. I am very familiar with their anatomical relationships (spatially) with the hypothalamus, 3rd ventricle, mammillary bodies, etc; however, I still do not quite understand what they are or what cell types comprise them.

Are they areas of grey matter? Are they some sort of modified ependymal cell layer of the 3rd ventricle floor?

Or are they areas of connective tissue that merely "house" white matter projections from the hypothalamus to the pituitary? So, to repeat the inquiry from above:

What cell types comprise the median eminence and the tuber cinereum?

And, moreover, what's the actual function of the cell types that comprise them?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia articles on both structures?

Comment: I do not see anything in the articles that even remotely talks about cell type...and seeing as that is the topic of this inquiry.

Answer (score -1):

The tuber cinereum is the "swelling" at the ventral surface of the hypothalamus (Subarachnoid space surface) at the base of the infundibular stalk. The median eminence (a circumventricular organ) is an elevation on the ventricular surface of the infundibular recess of the 3rd ventricle.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't answer the question as OP specifically says they are familiar with anatomy of said structures.

Comment: Since the question title asks specifically about the cell types, could you maybe edit your answer and add this information?